# Parse PoJo's JSON String attribute as object

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson, pojo

I would like to ask for help to make my code cleaner.

I have these PoJos for example:

```
class A {
  B b;
}

class B {
  int a;
  int b;
}
```

Data comes from HTTP request and the body is JSON. I want to parse this as class A by having the attribute b as a JSON string like below.

```
{
  "b":"{\"a\":1,\"b\":2}"
}
```

Currently I use custom parsing via Jackson's ObjectMapper and I do value validation by hand. Is it possible to apply some annotation on attribute 'b' that signs that it's a complex attribute wrapped in a string?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There is no need to do that. Jackson understands nested objects and will deserialize object `A` correctly so it will contain actual `B` instance.

Comment: If I let Jackson to do the deserialisation, it will complain about a missing constructor in B with a single String input. I hope that there's a way to tell Jackson to treat the JSON formatted string as a JSON object.

Comment: It seems your JSON is malformed. Can you remove quotes `"b":{\"a\":1,\"b\":2}`? Because of this Jackson deserializes it as String. If this format is intended (which is not recommended), then you could create a constructor Jackson wants and deserialize the String there.

Comment: That's the point. Value is always String. It has to be String.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom constructor with something like this:

```
class B {
  public B() {}
  public B(String value) {
       B b = new ObjectMapper().readValue(value, B.class);
       this.a = b.a;
       this.b = b.b;
  }
  int a;
  int b;
}
```

Another solution clould be to write a custom deserializer for B

Comment: This is a good solution however I look forward if Jackson can handle it via annotation. 
And don't forget to handle IOException here.